# Can I ask about installing Ubuntu on a Mac?

Tags: support, questions

I already have a similar question on Ask Ubuntu for installing Ubuntu  on a mac, but I want to post a question here. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about installing any operating system on Mac hardware is on-topic here, so feel free to ask related questions here. For a full list of topics that you can ask questions about here, see:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

However, keep in mind that cross-posting is prohibited and that you shouldn't [re-ask your question from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625686/trying-to-install-ubuntu-15-04-on-imac-not-working) here. If you feel that your question would be better suited here, flag for moderator attention on that question and ask that a moderator migrate it.

With regard to that specific question, whilst it's on topic here, I doubt you'll get any better attention here as IMO it's more to do with Ubuntu than the Mac hardware?

Comment: well, I think it's the hardware causing the problem... but it's worth a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

In general yes as it is about Apple hardware and Apple's boot mechanism does differ from other hardware.

However you should not ask the same question in two places on stack exchange although there is no way of managing duplicates across sites.